# ubuntu server and networkmanager

Tags: networking, server, network-manager

I have a problem with ubuntu server (16.10) and network manager.

The system is freshly installed (an offline install, with no ethernet cable attached) and at the first boot I plugged the cable into the ethernet port, I simply issued a `dhclient; apt-get update; apt-get install network-manager`, then I filled a file (`/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/EthernetInterface`) with this data:

```
[802-3-ethernet]
auto-negotiate=true
mac-address=<<ethernet card mac address>>

[connection]
id=EthernetInterface
uuid=<<randomly generated uuid>>
type=802-3-ethernet

[ipv6]
method=ignore

[ipv4]
method=manual
address1=172.16.20.153,172.16.0.254
dns=8.8.8.8;8.8.4.4;
```

(the ethernet MAC and UUID were properly filled).

Now, this was enough to make the PC automatically connect at boot, but now... No way.

The `nmcli d` command outputs all the network interfaces as unmanaged. File /etc/network/interfaces contains only the loopback device.

I tried also to edit the NetworkManager.conf file, setting `managed=true`, but without any luck.

How can I enable the interface? Or how can I track the problem?

Best regards

EDIT:

I know that usually the server it is not managed by NM (in fact it is not even pre-installed).

However I need the NetworkManager features (DBUS interface, automatic fallback on other connections when using mobile interfaces, integration with ModemManager). That's why I installed network-manager. However it is not working: maybe I have to change some default configuration, maybe I have to enable it, or maybe there is some rule somewhere to make it the default network connections handler. Do you know where? Otherwise I'll have to get a desktop version, but I preferred the server version since I didn't need a GUI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After comparing the configuration of two machines (one with ubuntu server 16.10 and NetworkManager, the other with Xubuntu 16.10) I found how to enable NetworkManager on the server version too.

You have to create a file `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml` and then write in it:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Reboot (or maybe just restart the appropriate service(s), I simply rebooted) and then NetworkManager will start managing all the devices in your system.

**DO NOT** write `managed=true` in the configuration file, though. This way if you write an interface in /etc/network/interfaces you will have it managed by ifupdown instead of NetworkManager (default behavior for nm).

Answer (score 9):

The Ubuntu Server edition isn't managed by the networkmanager. It's managed from the `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Look here to configure the `interfaces` file:

German wiki (cant find the english one now):
https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/interfaces/

Comment: I was about to say the same thing. The page you link to, however, is in German.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html Might be a useful link in English.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added some info on the question: mainly I need NM features, so I actually need it to manage the interfaces. That's why I installed it. But it appears that I have to enable it or to make it the default manager, so... Do you know how I can do that? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think answers are here:
[Network Manager refusing to manage wired interfaces](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838865/network-manager-refusing-to-manage-wired-interfaces/)

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1638842

Create empty /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
It should override default configuration in /usr/lib and enable wired devices. 
(it works for me)