# Ubuntu 20.04 Server 64-bit - Raspberry Pi 4 - The network icon shows me disconnected while in reality I am properly connected to the internet

Tags: server, 20.04, network-manager, raspberrypi, cinnamon

I have installed lightdm + cinnamon on Ubuntu 20.04 Server 64-bit for Raspberry Pi 4.
The systray network icon shows me disconnected from the internet while in reality I am connected.
None of the solutions offered by the internet solved my problem. This problem could be due to some missing package but I have no idea what it is.
I ran the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo reboot
sudo apt install --install-recommends lightdm
sudo apt install --install-recommends cinnamon-desktop-environment
sudo reboot
```

Cinnamon works but now I show you the network icon what it shows me with an image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer at this link:

[ubuntu server and networkmanager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/842773/ubuntu-server-and-networkmanager)

You have to create a file `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml` and then write in it:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Run:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

or reboot.