# Wired network - device not managed after upgrade to 17.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, wired, 17.04

After upgrade to 17.04 I can't connect to a wired ethernet via network manager. The indicator-network says: Ethernet Network - device not managed. System Settings > Network > Wired says: Wired Unmanaged.

Wifi connection is working well and wired connection managed via ifup/ifdown is also working well (when I put eth0 in /etc/network/interfaces).

My network config files look like this:

$ cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

Here is my ifconfig -a output:

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        ether 02:42:1c:34:04:c4  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 54:be:f7:76:35:32  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 18  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 352  bytes 25966 (25.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 352  bytes 25966 (25.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 7e:de:d9:4c:d6:4f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2170  bytes 1604327 (1.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2108  bytes 416467 (416.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Answer (score 6):

As [Zoltan Laczko](https://askubuntu.com/users/637434/zoltan-laczko) mentioned, from NetworkManager 1.2.4 (ubuntu 16.10) all non-wifi/wwan device are treated as unmanaged (see his answer in a similar question [Network Manager refusing to manage wired interfaces](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838865/network-manager-refusing-to-manage-wired-interfaces)). A solution is to create an empty file:

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
```

... that will overshadow/overwrite the one in /usr/lib and then restart the Network Manager.