# Bluetooth not working - Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: bluetooth, asus, 17.04

I've installed Zesty on my Zenbook UX510UX, but bluetooth is not working properly; I can connect my Honor phone, but I cannot send or receive anything, it says "Sorry, Ubuntu has experienced an internal error".

Does anyone know what could be causing the problem, and how to fix it?

EDIT:

```
journalctl -p err -e --since today | grep -i bluetooth
apr 29 16:04:39 user bluetoothd[767]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
apr 29 16:04:39 user bluetoothd[767]: Sap driver initialization failed.
apr 29 16:04:39 user bluetoothd[767]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
apr 29 16:04:42 user bluetoothd[767]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
apr 29 16:04:42 user bluetoothd[767]: Loading LTKs timed out for hci0
```

Comment: please try again, then post the last error messages w.r.t. bluetooth, use this command: `journalctl -p err -e --since today  | grep -i bluetooth `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be related to this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1645631

Try running (without sudo)

```
systemctl --user start obex
```

And then initiate a file transfer.

Comment: It worked but only for transfer, I'm still not able to receive anything via bluetooth (for example from my phone)

Comment: For a fix which lasts across reboots, run as normal user:
`systemctl --user enable obex`

Answer (score 0):

When I upgraded to 17.04 this network manager file was blocking my system from automatically managing my ethernet interface, maybe this is affecting bluetooth.

/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf

Content:

[keyfile]

unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan

I commented it all out, rebooted, and everything works fine now. It can also be deleted. Let me know if this works.

Reference: [Network Manager refusing to manage wired interfaces](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838865/network-manager-refusing-to-manage-wired-interfaces)